# Link grep as static library linux

Tags: c, makefile, grep, static-libraries

I know I need to build grep without linking, and change grep main function name to sth different. Then from object files create lib which I should link. This sound easy in theory, but does anybody tried that succesfully and can share instructuons what need to be changed in grep makefile?

Comment: You want all the code in GNU grep as a function you can call, as opposed to a standalone program you can invoke?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: There are many library choices in the pattern-matching market segment, including some that implement the tranditional `grep` regexp language(s). So the question of why you want this is important because there *might be an easier way to solve your problem*.

Comment: Also, do you need to actually change the `main` function to something different, or can you just use `pcresearch.h` etc. functions directly?